# Need to insert symbol inbetween the particular instance

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to insert underscore symbol inbetween the link and created as different attribute value:

My Input xml is:

```
<img imageid="36" alt="water" height="250" width="400" 
class="right" src="https://irctc.com/Services/Gets/Contents/imagesv1/Images/water" />
```

XSL I used as:

```
  <xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:element name="image">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@imageid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="alt">
        <xsl:value-of select="@alt"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="height">
        <xsl:value-of select="@height"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:value-of select="@width"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="align">
        <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output i got as:

```
 <image id="36"
 alt="water"
 height="250"
 width="400"
 align="right"
 href="https://irctc.com/Services/Gets/Contents/imagesv1/Images/water"/>
```

But i need the output as images-v1 needs to come along with the file name and i need underscore symbol inbetween that

Expected output:

```
 <image id="36"
 alt="water"
 height="250"
 width="400"
 align="right"
 href="imagesv1_water"/>
```

Please provide suggestion for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

to

```
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@src, '/')[position() = last()-2 or position() = last()]" separator="_"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below XSLT2.0 code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="img">
        <xsl:variable name="src_tokens" select="tokenize(@src, '/')"/>
        <image 
                id="{@imageid}"
                alt="{@alt}"
                height="{@height}"
                width="{@width}"
                align="{@class}"
                href="{$src_tokens[7]}_{$src_tokens[9]}"
                />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The values in braces are evaluated as xpath expressions when used for attributes.